# How to shrink fraction like excel in javascript

Tags: javascript, excel, excel-formula, formula, fractions

Here i need to calculate fraction **e.g.** *input value* is: **0.595**, as per fraction function it returns result 119/200. In MSExcel there many option but i need first three options.

> 1. up to one digit (1/4) - returns result (3/5)
> 2. up to two digits (21/25) - returns result (47/79)
> 3. up to three digits (312/943) - returns result (119/200)

here how can we find first 2 results?

**

```js
var strVal = 0.595;
var val1 = 595;
var val2 = Math.pow(10, 3);
var abs = Math.abs(this.getGcd(val1, val2));
document.getElementById('result').innerHTML = (val1 / abs) + '/' + (val2 / abs);

function getGcd(a, b) {
  return (b) ? this.getGcd(b, a % b) : a;
}
```

```html
<span id="result"></span>
```

**

Comment: So, what have you attempted?

Comment: i have attached the code that i have attempted. First 2 options i don't know how to achieve.